# How can I create a json payload for a POST request?

Tags: json, http, post, go, payload

```
request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url,bytes.NewBuffer(**myJsonPayload**))
```

I am trying to make post request with dynamic '**myJsonPayload**', which will be changing for different request.

Comment: I have tried the following: 

payload := []byte(`{
 "abc":xyz,
 "test":"test",
 }`)
jsonPayload, _ := json.Marshal(payload)
request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonPayload))

This actually works but static payload. All I want to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`Marshal` in the `encoding/json` package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_Marshal) of Go's standard library to encode your data as JSON.

Signature:

```
func Marshal(v interface{}) ([]byte, error)
```

Example from package docs, where input data happens to be a struct type with int, string, and string slice field types:

```
type ColorGroup struct {
    ID     int
    Name   string
    Colors []string
}
group := ColorGroup{
    ID:     1,
    Name:   "Reds",
    Colors: []string{"Crimson", "Red", "Ruby", "Maroon"},
}
b, err := json.Marshal(group)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use map for dynamically changing json payload. Below is the example code to do this.

```
payload := map[string]interface{}{"id":1, "name":"zahid"}
byts, _ := json.Marshal(payload)
fmt.Println(string(byts)) // {"id":1,"name":"zahid"}
```

Comment: This is not incorrect, but you should never suppress the error in the Marshal method.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [json#Encoder.Encode](//pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Encoder.Encode):

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "encoding/json"
   "net/http"
)

func main() {
   s, b := struct{Month, Day int}{12, 31}, new(bytes.Buffer)
   json.NewEncoder(b).Encode(s)
   r, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://stackoverflow.com", b)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   new(http.Client).Do(r)
}
```